# Implement searchfield functionality in sencha touch

Tags: extjs

I am getting problem that how to implement search field on tree store getting data from the server in sencha touch.Any working code will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should look into this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/nested_list) of the documentation to find out how to implement tree store. Use the methods [find()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-find) or [findBy()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore-method-findBy) to query the store.

Answer (score 2):

In Search field You can use key up event and filter a store as type charterer match to store and show filter data in list and on select on item in list you hide list as bellow done

```
{
    xtype: 'searchfield',
    name : 'Name',
    label: 'Name: ',
    id : 'Name',
    record:'Details',
    placeHolder: 'Name',
    listeners: {
      focus: function( field, e, eOpts ){
        Ext.getCmp('FilterDropDown').show();
      },
      keyup: function(field) {
        var value = field.getValue();
        var Store = Ext.getStore('Details');
        var FilterStore = Ext.getStore('FilterDetails');
        FilterStore.removeAll();
        count=0;
        var thisRegEx = new RegExp(value, 'i');
        for(cnt=0;cnt<Store.getCount();cnt++){
          if(thisRegEx.test(Store.data.items[cnt].data.name)){
            FilterStore.add({
                'id':Store.data.items[cnt].data.id,
                'name': Store.data.items[cnt].data.name,
                'email': Store.data.items[cnt].data.email

            });
          }
        }
       }
    }
  },
  {
    xtype:'FilterList',
    id: 'FilterDropDown',
    height:200,
    hidden : true,
    listeners: {
      itemtap: function( field, index, target, record, e, eOpts ){
         Ext.getCmp('Name').setValue(record.data.name); 
         Ext.getCmp('Email').setValue(record.data.email); 
         Ext.getCmp('Mobile').setValue(record.data.mobileno); 
         Ext.getCmp('FilderDropDown').hide();
      }
    }
  },
```

xtype FilterList code is

```
Ext.define('appname.view.FilterList', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'FilterList',
require: ['FilterDetails'],
config:{
  store: 'FilterDetails',
  scrollable: true,
  cls: 'drop_down_list',
  ui: 'round',
  itemTpl: '<div>{name}</div>'
}
});
```

It will help you :)

Comment: I know this way seems longer, but this would be the method you'd choose for optimising your code when your dataset gets heavier.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is already in the store when you search this isn't too difficult to implement using the methods referenced by speznaz.

In your view have a xtype "searchfield" or "textfield".

```
{
    xtype: "searchfield",
}
```

In the controller bind a "keyup" event to this field.

```
refs: {
   searchfield: 'mypanel searchfield'
},
control: {
   searchfield: {
      keyup: 'doSearch'
   }
}
```

For your function to search something like:

```
doSearch: function(searchfield, e, eOpts) {
     var searchterm = searchfield.getValue();
     var store = Ext.getStore('myStore');

     // Now just customise the search options
     store.find(fieldName, value, [startIndex], [anyMatch], [caseSensitive], [exactMatch] );
}
```

This is assuming you want to search on keyup. You may want to use the "action" event instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have data in the store.
Here is the working code:

```
{
    xtype: "searchfield",
    name:'searchName'
}
```

In the controller bind a "keyup" event to this field.

```
refs: {
searchName: 'searchfield[name=searchName]'
},
control: {
  searchName: {
    keyup: 'doSearch'
  }
}
```

For your function to search :

```
    doSearch: function(field, e, eOpts) {
    var searchterm = field.getValue();
     var store = Ext.getStore('myStore');

   // Now just customise the search options
    store.filter(fieldName,searchterm);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try.sencha.com it has lot of examples on how to use the framework. 
You need to use an Ajax store for getting data from server. I think [this](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/first_app) guide will be a good start for that, it also implements a tree store.

This [example](http://try.sencha.com/touch/2.0.0/examples/list-search/) explains how to filter data in a list based on what you type in a searchfield.

Hope it helps